# SpringData MongoDB performance bug/issue after update

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-4

After updating SpringData MongoDB from 1.6.1 to 1.7.0 I am experiencing performance issues.

Especially bad is this query:

```
@Query(value = "{$and: [{?0 : { $exists: true }}, {'lastChanged': {$gt: ?1}}] }")
List<Event> findAllByPrefixedInvitedUserAndLastChangedLessThan(String prefixedUserID, LocalDateTime lastChanged);
```

where the `prefixedUserID` is querying an embedded document (accessed by the string `"invitedUser.userID"`, which is, by the way, a thing that I could not solve using standart query syntax nor with custom query)

The actual problem is that this query takes about 8-10sec with a database containing 4 (!!!) events.

To investigate on this poor performance I reduced the log level for spring data to debug and got a log file of ~20.0000 lines for the single function call (the `getAllEventsForUser` function from the class `de.steilerdev.myVerein.server.controller.user.EventController` is called -> can be found in my [repo](https://github.com/steilerDev/myVerein/blob/master/Code/Server/)). I put the log into [this gist](https://gist.github.com/steilerDev/f00e765a844a02b643f0#file-springdata-mongodb-performance-issue).

As you can see `MongoDbUtils [doGetDB] - Getting Mongo Database name=[myVerein]` is called thousands of times. I am unable to really debug this problem, so I hope any of the devs of the project is looking into this.

Another possibility is a configuration problem, but I could not find any notice in the changelog, which said I had to change any specific entry when updating. Nevertheless you can find all database and spring related configuration in this folder of my repo (see link above):

```
/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/configuration/
```

(Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to post more than two links)

I hope there is someone who can help me on this problem. Thanks in advance!

P.S.: The repeatedly call of the `doGetDB` function occurs at all of my query, but less often ("only" a couple of hundred times)

P.P.S.: I am running MongoDB version 3.0.1

Comment: Any chance you add a test case that reproduces the log output? Calling a repository method or the like?

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for, but yes calling this repository function is causing most of this output. The complete log was generated by the function I mentioned above, which can be found in the linked github repo. It is the `getAllEventsForUser` function from the class [de.steilerdev.myVerein.server.controller.user.EventController][1]. I hope that's what you are looking for.     [1]: https://github.com/steilerDev/myVerein/blob/master/Code/Server/src/main/java/de/steilerdev/myVerein/server/controller/user/EventController.java

Comment: I am looking for some code that I can execute to reproduce the log output you see. That's usually a test case.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately I don't have any Unit tests (yet). But you could do the following: 1) Clone the repo and run the java server (located at /Code/Server/) using Tomcat 8 and a local Mongo 2) Open the index page in your browser (this creates a database example within the "myVerein" database) 3) Log into the REST-API by using curl or similiar, posting username=frank@steiler.eu and password=asdf to /api/login (should respond with 200 OK) 4) GET the resource /api/user/event with the parameter lastChanged=2015-03-28T01:00:00 This sould take a while and produce the problem

Comment: Well, be advised that it's unlikely for you to get help if you can't provide a minimal reproducing test case. No one's going to wade through a plethora of code, run an app, interact with it. If I can't reproduce the problem with a mvn clean test, I unfortunately can't spent any time on it.

Comment: All right I am going to create that test case as soon as possible, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Thanks for your patience and spotting that issue! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I am suspecting here is that the `invitedDivision` property in `Event` is cause the issues. DBRefs are loaded eagerly by default which means that you'll see a lookup for each document in the collection.

You might wanna try setting the `lazy` attribute of the `@DBRef` annotation here to avoid the eager lookups. Also switching to referring to IDs and manually resolving the `Divisions` via their repository could be an option, too.

That you see the change happening with the upgrade to 1.7 is very likely related to the changes we made to assure compatibility to the MongoDB 3.0 driver. I've filed [DATAMONGO-1193](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1193) to fix that. I also file [DATAMONGO-1194](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1193) to fix that problem for usage with the MongoDB 3.0 driver as it's gonna hit users upgrading to the new driver, too. That said, the workarounds documented above should work in any case.

Comment: Wow that did it! Just a follow up question: Why is lazy not enabled by default? Is there a major performance issue when using lazy everywhere, or is there a problem when doing that?